# Web scraping - can't get a table present in the webpage

Tags: c#, winforms, web-scraping

I'm parsing the HTML of a webpage for getting some information. In my webpage, I have a `<table>` which I'm trying to access. But when I write the following code, 0 elements are returned:

```
WebBrowser csexBrowser = new WebBrowser();
HtmlElementCollection table2 = this.csexBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table");
```

Here, table2 has nothing. 0 elements.I'm using winforms.

EDIT: [This is the link](http://www.nsopw.gov/en-US/Search). If you search for a name, then it will show you some results in a table.

Comment: Usually when I run into something like this, the table is being added via javascript which doesn't get parsed by the scraper.  I haven't examined this example, though - no idea if that's relevant to you.

Comment: @Bobson is right. That's encountered some times while scraping. Your scraper needs to be able to process javascript as well in order to add dynamic rows to a table.

Comment: @jlafay: how would I process javascript then?

Comment: When are you navigating?

Answer (score 0):

There is a verification step which precedes access to the link you provided. In the http://www.nsopw.gov/en-US/Search/Verification document, there are no tables.

Are you sure you pass the verification URL first?

**[EDIT]**

Please try this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebBrowser csexBrowser = new WebBrowser();

    //here we say what we want to do when the Navigated event occurs
    csexBrowser.Navigated += csexBrowser_Navigated;

    //this takes some time
    csexBrowser.Navigate("http://www.nsopw.gov/en-US/Search");
}

void csexBrowser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    //here the document is loaded and we will find the table
    HtmlElementCollection table2 = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementsByTagName("table");
}
```

Comment: first, you do a verification.then you get to search for a name.then, when you click on the search button, a table should appear

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on navigating with a browser then you must wait for the navigation to finish. Personally I hate this method plus the event fire most people go for can multi-trigger I have found.

Do this:

```
csexBrowser.Navigate(Url);
        while (csexBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Simply navigates to the given url and doesn't continue until the page has finished loading. 
Done and done.